# Como criar uma função em R para abrir um arquivo .txt?

Tags: r

Preciso criar uma função em R para que a mesma me peça o nome de um arquivo em meu diretório, assim como leia esse arquivo. Estou tentando o código abaixo mas não está funcionando.

```
function(DNAseq){
    DNASeq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name")
    FASTA <- read.table(DNASeq)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isto irá funcionar, adicionei um loop que identifica, por exemplo, se o arquivo é ".csv" ou ".xlsx";

```
        setwd(dir = 'c:/r_projects/temp')

        request <- function(request) {
        x <- select.list(list.files())

        if (length(grep(x, pattern = "\\.csv$")) == 1) {
        file <- read.csv(x)
    
        } else if (length(grep(x, pattern = "\\.xlsx$")) == 1) {
        file <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(x)
    
        } else {
        NULL
    
         }
        }
        request()
```

[image: selection da função criada]

Comment: Muito bom!! Obrigado